# Rendering only partial parts of html page to pdf multiple times using jspdf and html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

My existing code is able to render the whole body of the HTML page to the PDF. Kindly check the code below.

```
function exportScorecard() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var source = $('#main')[0];
    var options = { background: '#fff' };


    doc.addHTML(source, options, function () {
        doc.save('scorecard.pdf');
    });

}
```

Below is also the result of the code.
[image]

But my goal is to **break down** the current result **per chart/div**. Like a decent report, I am planning to **add text analysis below each chart**. How can I **ONLY** grab the `div` containing the `canvas` chart?

I have tried using **multiple** `addHTML()` functions and it renders nothing since I have to take out the `doc.save()` function, therefore giving me a **blank page**.

Thank you very much!